# How to get expect -c to work in single line rather than script

Tags: shell, command-line, scp, expect

Running:

```
my_machine~/opt/ams/data/ep/success$ expect -c "spawn /usr/bin/scp xmlEventLog_2010-03-22T14-28-36_PFS_1_2.xml adaptive@10.10.12.17:/opt/ams/epf_3_4/xmlEventLog_2010-03-22T14-28-36_PFS_1277900174_2.xml; expect { '*password:*' { send 'ad'\r\n }}"
```

Does not seem to work as I am still asked for the password.

```
spawn /usr/bin/scp xmlEventLog_2010-03-22T14-28-36_PFS_1_2.xml adaptive@10.10.12.17:/opt/ams/epf_3_4/xmlEventLog_2010-03-22T14-28-36_PFS_1277900174_2.xml
adaptive@10.10.12.17's password:
```

If I run it as ascript it runs ok.

```
my_machine~/opt/ams/data/ep/success$ ./try.sh
spawn /usr/bin/scp xmlEventLog_2010-03-22T14-28-36_PFS_1_2.xml adaptive@10.10.12.17:/opt/ams/epf_3_4/xmlEventLog_2010-03-22T14-28-36_PFS_1277900174_2.xml
adaptive@10.10.12.17's password:
xmlEventLog_2010-03-22T14-28-36_PFS_1_2.xml                                                                      100%   13MB  13.2MB/s   00:01
my_machine~/opt/ams/data/ep/success$ cat try.sh
#!/bin/bash
expect -c "
        spawn /usr/bin/scp xmlEventLog_2010-03-22T14-28-36_PFS_1_2.xml adaptive@10.10.12.17:/opt/ams/epf_3_4/xmlEventLog_2010-03-22T14-28-36_PFS_1277900174_2.xml
        expect {
          "*password:*" { send "ad"\r\n; interact }
          eof { exit }
        }
        exit
        "

my_machine~/opt/ams/data/ep/success$
```

I would like to run this in a one line command rather than a script. Has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks in advance

A

I answered my own question below

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Got it:
The following code scps a file called Sean_Lilly.zip from my box to another box without entering a password:

```
expect -c "spawn /usr/bin/scp Sean_Lilly.zip adaptive@10.10.12.17:/opt/ams/epf_3_4/Sean_Lilly.zip; sleep 5; expect -re \"password\"; send \"ad\r\n\"; set timeout -1; expect -re \"100%\";"
```

I know this can be done by setting passwordless ssh access between the two boxes but I wanted to do it in one command line using expect. Thanks fuzzy lollipop for the inspiration. Note if you run expect -d -c "spawn ... you get excellent debug on what is happening including whether your regex is good enough

Comment: Nice. On OS X replace `\r\n` with just `\r`.

Comment: Why `sleep`, isn't the `expect` waiting for the previous `spawn` command?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `;` on the first one line example at the end of the last command. And there is a better way to pattern match the password.

try the following:

```
expect -c "spawn /usr/bin/scp xmlEventLog_2010-03-22T14-28-36_PFS_1_2.xml adaptive@10.10.12.17:/opt/ams/epf_3_4/xmlEventLog_2010-03-22T14-28-36_PFS_1277900174_2.xml; expect -re \".*password.*\"; send 'ad\r\n';"
```

Comment: that could be something failing silently, like the wrong password or something

Comment: thought of that. when you run the command it prints out the spawn that it uses. I copied the spawn into the shell and gave the password as above and it worked manually. If the pattern is being correctly matched it does not seem to be sending the password

Comment: almost there... the problem is that after you are sending the password ... the expect script exits, just add an extra "expect eof" at the end, and you should be fine.